# TypeScript: Carrying a method with overloading signatures without losing the overload

Tags: typescript

The example is with strict null checking.
Consider I have the following function declaration:

```
declare function f(value: null, multiplier: number): null;
declare function f(value: string, multiplier: number): number;
declare function f(value: string | null, multiplier: number): number | null;
```

Now I want to carry it like this:

```
const f2 = (value) => f(value, 2);
```

Seems like the inferred parameter type is "any" and the inferred return type is "number | null".

Is there a way to make typescript infer the new function type correctly so it preserves overloads, without having to redefine all signatures?

The expected call signature results should be identical to this:

```
function f2(value: null): null;
function f2(value: string): number;
```

Comment: No, you would have to write out appropriate overloads for `f2`.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way in typescript to partially fill a functions call signature from another function. Like it won't assume what `value` param.

Here's an example for clarification:

```
function someOtherFunction(x: number) {}
function test(x) {
   // we can't assume `x` is number just because it's used as one for input to the other function.
   someOtherFunction(x, 5);
}
```

I'd refactor it to be something like this instead:

```
type ValueType = null | string;
declare function f(value: ValueType, multiplier: number): number | null;

const f2 = (value: ValueType) => f(value, 2);
```

The closest thing I can come up with is something like this:

```
declare function f<T = string | null>(
  value: T,
  multiplier: number
): T extends string ? number : null;

const f2 = (value: string | null) => f<typeof value>(value, 5);

const x = f2(null); // x: number | null
const x2 = f2("5"); // x2: number | null
```

But I think this pretty much just does the function overloading automatically using conditional types...

Comment: The refactor proposition is not good enough since I want to assume non-null output for non-null input, which requires the overload declarations.
Is the only way to accomplish this rewrite the overloads in f2?

Comment: I think I see what you mean, I don't believe there is a solution for this then... you probably just need to define `f2` function manually. Look at the way I setup `f` declaration, might help you get something similar going for `f2`

Comment: Yeah using generics instead of overloads might help, I'll look into it, thanks!